# Python is installed, but Python version is not showing

Tags: python, windows-11

[image]

I have tried various methods but didn't get any solution. There is also a correct path in the system environment variable.

Comment: And `python.exe --version`?

Comment: Often, `py` seems to work on Windows as an alias for Python. Try that instead.

Comment: Hello Argha Saha! Most likely your problem is solved by using the appropriate Command "python3" instead.

Comment: I have tried already python3 but it didn't work

Comment: You might need to close the Windows Terminal window and any other console windows you might have open (e.g. Powershell, CMD) in order for path changes to take effect. Once you've closed all windows, open a new instance of Windows Terminal and type `python`.

Comment: I have tried those already but no solution

Comment: In `C:\Users\sahaa\python`, run the command `dir` and share the output.

Comment: Please do not provide text as image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

Using `py -3 --version` command in terminal have solved this problem.